# How to get Share Folder information

Tags: apex, soql, rest-api

Is that possible to get the share information for a particular folder using soql/apex or rest api here is what I'm trying to see for the `DreamHouse Reports` who can access that folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think metadata api : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_foldershare.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve that:

1. By using REST API:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_folders_shares.htm

[image]

2. By using Metadata API: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_foldershare.htm